# OpenCart throws JS error 'Cannot read property "document" of null' when hosted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, opencart

When I'm trying opencart on my local, it seems that it's working fine. But when I uploaded to the hosting/server, some errors appear, please see below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
f.each.contents @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
e.extend.map @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 
f.fn.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3 
(anonymous function) @ crossdomain.php?session_id=66e844dc45af19ce293981cdd9b22b67:566 
n @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 o.fireWith @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
e.extend.ready @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
```

What seems to be the problem? Because in my local, these errors doens't appear. Thanks.

Comment: did you Google that before posting?

Comment: Yes! But I didn't find any answer. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Sounds to me like you're passing null to jquery and its choking on it. Where is your code that calls it?

Comment: I'm using opencart, i dont know particular when this .js is called. @Chris

Comment: You should be able to determine when this is being called.  In Chrome, you can use developer tools to break you into debug mode when an uncaught exception is seen.  (Break on uncaught exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference between running hosted and running locally is the security treatment of network calls.  The reference to crossdomain.php in your stack trace suggests that you're running into this.

If so, then there are two possible solutions:

If you're running in Flash:  You need to host a [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file at the root of the remote domain that grants permission to the local domain (or, as in this example, everyone):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This file must always be at the root of the remote domain, e.g., http://something.com/crossdomain.xml .

If Flash is not involved, then [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is the security mechanism responsible for blocking this call, and you need to configure the remote web server to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response to the URL you're reaching out to.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: If I may ask, where to configure this remote we server you've mention?

Comment: Well, the whole point of this security mechanism is that, if you don't have the ability to get the remote server to respond saying you're OK, you can't do this.

Comment: However, for Flash, you'd just upload crossdomain.xml into the root of the web server.  If you are using a CMS that prevents this, you'll have to get around that.

Comment: For CORS, this depends on the web server.  For Apache, see http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html ; basically, you'd edit one of your .conf files or upload an .htaccess file if you need this to apply to only one directory.

Comment: crossdomain.xml WORKED! THANK YOU! YOU SAVED ME! :))

Comment: Thank you again!!! Big help! :)